# Spring Boot Server REST API reads null values from JSON object

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a REST API setup using Spring Boot. I'm attempting to send a JSON object in a POST request to the API to read the values and store them in a SQL Server database table, but it doesn't read all of the values.

This is the JSON object I'm sending:

`{     "filename":"recording1POST",      "creationdate":"13.11.2023",     "userid":1,     "relativefilepath":"filepathPOST",     "camerasid":1 }`

The is the class I'm mapping it to:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

//Entity annotation defines class as being mapped to a table.
@Entity
@Table(name="Files")
public class Recording {
@Id//Marks the primary key of the table.
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)//Primary key auto-increments.
private int fileid;

    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String filename;
    
    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private String creationdate;
    
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private int userid;
    
    @Column(name = "relativefilepath")
    private String relativefilepath;
    
    @Column(name = "camerasid")
    private int camerasid;
    
    public int getFileID() {
        return fileid;
    }
    
    public void setFileID(int fileID) {
        this.fileid = fileID;
    }
    
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    
    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    
    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationdate;
    }
    
    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationdate = creationDate;
    }
    
    public int getUserID() {
        return userid;
    }
    
    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userid = userID;
    }
    
    public String getRelativeFilepath() {
        return relativefilepath;
    }
    
    public void setRelativeFilepath(String relativeFilepath) {
        this.relativefilepath = relativeFilepath;
    }
    
    public int getCamerasID() {
        return camerasid;
    }
    
    public void setCamerasID(int camerasID) {
        this.camerasid = camerasID;
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following result:

[Spring Boot Server REST API not reading values from JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNUug.png)

I haven't been able to find any questions with my specific problem. What might be causing this?

Edit: These are my database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    userid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(255),
    password varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Cameras (
    cameraid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    cameraname varchar(255),
    camusername varchar(255),
    campassword varchar(255),
    userid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Files (
    fileid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    filename varchar(255),
    creationdate datetime DEFAULT(getdate()),
    userid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(userid),
    relativefilepath varchar(255),
    camerasid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cameras(cameraid)
);
```

Comment: share your controller class and paste stracktrace instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change setter/getter as below

```
 public int getFileid() {
        return fileid;
    }

    public void setFileid(int fileid) {
        this.fileid = fileid;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getCreationdate() {
        return creationdate;
    }

    public void setCreationdate(String creationdate) {
        this.creationdate = creationdate;
    }

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getRelativefilepath() {
        return relativefilepath;
    }

    public void setRelativefilepath(String relativefilepath) {
        this.relativefilepath = relativefilepath;
    }

    public int getCamerasid() {
        return camerasid;
    }

    public void setCamerasid(int camerasid) {
        this.camerasid = camerasid;
    }
```

Comment: That was the problem. I have changed them as you specified and it is receiving the values now. Thanks very much.